# Rails + Heroku: App crashing on Heroku but working on local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, enums

I've just changed one of my models to support an **enum** (available since rails 4.1 I think). My app continues to run on my local server but when I deploy to Heroku I get an `App Crashed` error in the logs and an `Application Error` when I visit the site. If I remove the enum declaration line from my model it works again. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :new ,:old, :both ]
end
```

Heroku logs:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=005c1584-7217-4685-b41e-a5657122d9e2 fwd="89.242.203.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: What do your logs show?

Comment: Does the rails version on Herki support enums?

Comment: @FreddyWetson They support 4.1.1 so I presume enum support is included.

Comment: @JohnBeynon Updated with logs

Comment: some *more* logs around this event would be more helpful :)

Comment: @catsby that's all I'm getting unfortunately. The heroku server launches and it crashes immediately. That's the only log.

Comment: there will be more useful info in the logs...

Answer (score 0):

It's a very vague question, to be honest.  Here's my precursory answer though. Check if you're precompiling your assets in your app. If that doesn't work, see if you're using Postgres as your production databse adapter in your gemfile.